# How does a Hive heal?

Tags: natural-selection-2

When injured, Kharaa lifeforms can move to a [Hive](http://wiki.unknownworlds.com/ns2/Hive) and be healed. Damaged Kharaa structures in the vicinity of a Hive will also be healed. During game play, it appears that the Hive heals differently than the [Crag](http://wiki.unknownworlds.com/index.php/Crag).

How much and at what rate does the Hive heal?

Is there a limit to how many players and structures a Hive can heal at a time (Crags for example, can only heal 3 targets at a time)?

Is there any difference in healing between the different types of Hives (Shade Hive, Crag Hive, Shift Hive and Hive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How much and at what rate does the Hive heal?

8% of max health/armor per second

> Is there a limit to how many players and structures a Hive can heal at a time (Crags for example, can only heal 3 targets at a time)?

No

> Is there any difference in healing between the different types of Hives (Shade Hive, Crag Hive, Shift Hive and Hive)?

No